# How to enable core files on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, ulimit, sysctl, dump

I am trying to enable core files on a machine running CentOS 6; however, nothing I have tried has produced core files…here is what I have done:

Added the following two lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
*     hard    core    unlimited
*     soft    core    unlimited
```

Added the following line to `/etc/sysconfig/init`:

```
DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT='unlimited'
```

Added the following line to `/etc/profile`:

```
ulimit -c unlimited > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Added the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.core_pattern = '/srv/core/%p_%t.core'
fs.suid_dumpable = 1
```

I made sure that `/srv/core` exists and has `777` permissions. The I executed `init 6` to reboot the OS. Upon the system coming back up, I executed the following C script in an attempt to produce a core file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  kill(getpid(), SIGQUIT);
}
```

It does not produce a core file :(

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the missing `'` at the end of the line for `/etc/sysconfig/init` a bad copy/paste or is it really missing?

Comment: Just a copy/paste error…fixed that in the question

Comment: I'd change your file mode from 777 to 1777 to prevent 'accidental' deletion of one users core files by another...

Comment: can you show ulimit -a ?

Answer (score 2):

If your program is running as root, then the limits.conf entries you added would not apply.  "*" applies to all users except for root.

If your program is running as root, add the following:

```
root     hard    core    unlimited
root     soft    core    unlimited
```

Also, ensure that SELinux is not preventing the writing of the core dump.

```
getenforce
```

If SELinux is running, verify that audit is running, try to get your core dump and then do:

```
grep -i denied /var/log/audit/auditd
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is that the path is quoted for core_pattern. Try this instead:

```
kernel.core_pattern = /srv/core/%p_%t.core
```